# SSRS - Chart Axis max - always include 'at least' a number

Tags: reporting-services

I have a chart that shows an index over time, so hopefully the line hovers around 1.  I always want 0 included as the floor of the chart.  That's easy enough.  The tricky request is always 'at least' having 1.5 as the max.  I never want the maximum of the chart to go under 1.5, but it can go up.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, this seems to work in a quick test:

```
=IIf(Max(Fields!IndexPerformance.Value) < 1.5, 1.5, Nothing)
```

Which assumes you have a field called `IndexPerformance`, of course.

Some simple data, with a max field < 1.5:

[image]

Set the axis intervals to something sensible and apply the expression above to the Maximum property:

[image]

Chart looks OK:

[image]

Change the data slightly, max value > 1.5:

[image]

Chart now increases the axis to accommodate:

[image]